# Generating a list with duplicate entries

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I get a function that gives the following output?

```
listX = {a, b, c, d}
numberX = 3
myDuplicatesList[listX, numberX]
```

> {{a,a,a},{b,b,b},{c,c,c},{d,d,d}}

Comment: [Wolfram Challenges](https://challenges.wolfram.com/challenge/listify-the-elements-of-a-list).

Answer (score 10):

I like using [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) for problems like this:

```
KroneckerProduct[listX, ConstantArray[1, numberX]]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

The [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct) approach should be much faster than the others for large vectors.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively:

```
listX = {a, b, c};
numberX = 3;
Table[ConstantArray[i, numberX], {i, listX}]
```

> {{a, a, a}, { b, b, b}, {c, c, c}}

Or:

```
listX = {a, b, c, d};
numberX = 3;

Transpose@Table[i, {numberX}, {i, listX}]
```

Comment: Or `ConstantArray[#, numberX] & /@ listX`

Comment: No need to use Transpose, just invert the order of the arguments: Table[i, {i,listX}, numberX]

Answer (score 5):

[`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[listX &, numberX, 1, Transpose[{##}] &]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

[`ArrayPad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html):

```
ArrayPad[List /@ listX, {0, {0, numberX - 1}}, "Fixed"]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

[`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html):

```
PadRight[{#}, numberX, "Fixed"] & /@ listX  )* or *)
PadRight[List /@ listX, {Automatic, numberX}, "Fixed"]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

[`TensorProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct.html):

```
TensorProduct[listX, Array[1 &, numberX]]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

[`ArrayResample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html):

```
ArrayResample[listX, Scaled @ numberX , "Bin", Resampling -> "NearestLeft"]
```

> {a, a, a, b, b, b, c, c, c, d, d, d}

```
Partition[%, numberX]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

Answer (score 4):

one way might be

```
listX    = {a, b, c, d}
numberX  = 3
Transpose[{listX}].{Table[1, {numberX}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
Transpose@ConstantArray[listX, numberX]
```

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}

Answer (score 3):

Yet Another Way:

```
Flatten[ConstantArray[{listX}, numberX], {2, 3}]
```

And another (the last argument `1` is necessary only when `listX` is not a flat list):

```
Outer[Times, listX, ConstantArray[1, numberX], 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Transpose[{listX}[[ConstantArray[1, numberX]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listX = {a, b, c, d};
numberX = 3;
```

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[listX, {g_} :> Table[g, numberX]]
```

**Using `Replace`:**

```
listX // Replace[#, a_ :> Table[a, numberX], {1}] &
```

---

> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b}, {c, c, c}, {d, d, d}}